# How's the 2nd generation packaging today?

Tags: salesforcedx, packaging-2

I am thinking of using the 2nd generation packaging for my project for automation. I'm wondering if it's already ready for production use. What are the limitations? When will it go GA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Second Generation Packages are still in BETA (As of Summer 18 , v43.0) .

From salesforce docs

> As a beta feature, Second-Generation Packaging is a preview and isn’t part of the “Services” under your master subscription agreement with Salesforce. Use this feature at your sole discretion, and make your purchase decisions only on the basis of generally available products and features. Salesforce doesn’t guarantee general availability of this feature within any particular time frame or at all, and we can discontinue it at any time. This feature is for evaluation purposes only, not for production use. It’s offered as is and isn’t supported, and Salesforce has no liability for any harm or damage arising out of or in connection with it. All restrictions, Salesforce reservation of rights, obligations concerning the Services, and terms for related Non-Salesforce Applications and Content apply equally to your use of this feature.

There are two variations of it

**1.Unlocked Packages** - Targeted for System Integrators and Enterprise applications . These can be treated similar to the unmanaged packages but know that they are upgradable and developer has more control over it .

**2.Managed packages** - Geared Towards ISV .

Problems that Second Generation packages will address are as below

1. Multiple packages per namespace, so you can better organize your
   source and easily share Apex code. You can use public Apex classes
   across packages rather than global Apex classes.
2. Feature branch development and testing
3. Completely API-driven functionality.
4. Packages can built directly from the source
5. Ease of development and distribution of dependent packages

There is no specific date on its GA and there is a list of components that you cant port to the packaging 2.0 as of today (June 1st 2018)

The list of components that are supported are documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_plan_component_types.htm)

If your application uses onr of these components that packaging 2.0 does not support yet then you will have to wait for it before adopting .

Comment: The "locked packages" feature was removed in Summer '18.

Comment: Reference about locked packages pilot suspended in Summer '18, https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_sfdx_packaging_locked_packages.htm